# How do I fix 'access_denied' error when using M2M to connect to Auth0 Management API v2 in my React Native app?

Tags: node.js, react-native, auth0

I am new to auth0 and new to building an app for phones.

I have integrated auth0 into my project which is a react native application.

Therefore, I am currently utilizing a native project in here.

Also I did create an M2M to help me connect to an API to make changes to users however I am getting an error

> "access_denied: {“error”:“access_denied”,“error_description”:"Client
> is not authorized to access "https://[URL-ACCESS]/api/v2/". You need
> to create a "client-grant" associated to this API. See: Auth0
> Management API v2

I am not sure if I am missing any settings or any other steps. Please note that I did authorize the M2M and granted all of the scope to it.

here is the code I use, I am making a call from my server which is Node.js my front end is passing values React Native.

```
const express = require('express');
const { ManagementClient } = require('auth0');
const url = require('url');
const { authenticate } = require('./middlewares');
const axios = require('axios');
const auth0 = new ManagementClient({
  domain: process.env.AUTH0_DOMAIN,
  clientId: process.env.AUTH0_CLIENT_ID,
  clientSecret: process.env.AUTH0_CLIENT_SECRET,
  scope: 'read:users update:users'
});
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/authenticated', (req, res) => {
  res.send('You are authenticated!');
});

router.get('/admin', [authenticate, authenticate], (req, res) => {
  // You can add additional checks here to confirm the user has the 'admin' role.
  res.send('You are an admin!');
});


// Function to get Management API token
async function getManagementApiToken() {
  try {
    const response = await axios({
      method: 'POST',
      url: 'https://[URL-TOKEN]/oauth/token',
      headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json' },
      data: {
        client_id: process.env.M2M_CLIENT_ID,
        client_secret: process.env.M2M_CLIENT_SECRET,
        audience: '[AUDIENCE]/api/v2/',
        grant_type: 'client_credentials',
      },
    });

    return response.data.access_token;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Failed to get Management API token:', error);
    throw error;
  }
}

router.put('/update-profile', [authenticate], async (req, res) => {
  const { name, email, password, picture } = req.body;


  let managementApiToken;
  try {
    console.log('Getting Management API token...');
    managementApiToken = await getManagementApiToken();
    console.log('Got Management API token:', managementApiToken);

  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Failed to get Management API token:', error);
    return res.status(500).json({ error: 'Failed to update profile. Please try again.' });
  }

  // Validate name
  if (name && name.trim() === '') {
    return res.status(400).json({ error: 'Name cannot be empty.' });
  }

  // Validate email
  const emailRegex = /\S+@\S+\.\S+/;
  if (email && (!emailRegex.test(email))) {
    return res.status(400).json({ error: 'Invalid email.' });
  }

  // Validate password
  const passwordRegex = /^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d@$!%*?&]{8,}$/;
  if (password && !passwordRegex.test(password)) {
    return res.status(400).json({ error: 'Password must be at least 8 characters long and contain at least one uppercase letter, one lowercase letter, one number, and one special character.' });
  }

  // Validate profile picture
  // If picture is provided, validate it (e.g., check it is a well-formed URL, and optionally that it points to a known good domain).
  if (picture && !url.parse(picture).hostname) {
    return res.status(400).json({ error: 'Invalid picture URL.' });
  }

  try {
    const userId = req.user.sub;
    const data = {};
    if (name) data.name = name;
    if (email) data.email = email;
    if (picture) data.picture = picture;
    if (password) data.password = password;

    // Update the user profile in Auth0
    await auth0.updateUser({ id: userId }, data, {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Authorization: `Bearer ${managementApiToken}`,
      },
    });

    res.status(200).json({ message: 'Profile updated successfully!' });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Failed to update profile:', error);
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'Failed to update profile. Please try again.' });
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```

I need to be able to update user information that is being sent from my front end react native

Answer (score 0):

Resolved the issue.

Solution: Was using my native project clientId and secret instead of the M2M in the call. Therefore was getting an error